# Amazon S3: getSignedUrl: "Missing required key 'Bucket' in params"

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Struggled here for two days. I am kind of new to javascript and AWS so any hint will be appreciate.

I have 11 buckets. Others work fine except this one.

When I pass in another bucket name and key value, it works, but when I pass in the one I needed I get error: "Missing required key 'Bucket' in params".

For example: 
If I pass in bucket: 'businesspicture', it successfully load the picture I need.

```
$scope.$watch("userInfo.picture", function (imageValue) {
    var defaultIcon = '/images/defaultuser.jpg';
    if (imageValue !== defaultIcon && !imageValue.startsWith("https://")) {
        pictureServices.picture.getPictureFromS3({
            fileName: imageValue,
            bucket: "userpicture"
        }, {}, function (pic) {
            $scope.iconPreviewImage = pic.url;
            $scope.userInfo.picture = imageValue;
        }, function (error) {
            dialogService.showNgResourceError(error);
        });
    }
});
```

pictureService.js.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('../s3_config.json');
var photoBuckets = new AWS.S3();

exports.getPictureFromS3 = function(fileName, bucketName) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var params = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName
        };
        photoBuckets.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function(err, url){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            } else{
                awsurl = {url:url};
                resolve(awsurl);
            }

        });

    });
};
```

Comment: Just in case it's something silly:
You're passing an object:
`pictureServices.picture.getPictureFromS3({
            fileName: imageValue,
            bucket: "userpicture"
        }...)`

but the definition has two arguments
`exports.getPictureFromS3 = function(fileName, bucketName) {`

Comment: @Hodrobond I dont really understand. So you mean I should not pass an object to a scope.watch function?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure your passed arguments match what the function expects.

with the definition: `getPictureFromS3 = function(fileName, bucketName)` and invocation:`getPictureFromS3({ fileName: imageValue, bucket: "userpicture" }...)` -
 `fileName` would be an object that contains `fileName` and `bucket`

Comment: @Hodrobond Hmm, that sounds correct. But when i pass in two arguments, such as pictureServices.picture.getPictureFromS3(imageValue,"userpictureebiztie"), the "missing bucket" error disappears but still no images shows up. I console.log the value get from this function and it returns an object. This object includes characters "userpicture", however a picture url is expected.

Comment: are you sure `imageValue` is correct?

Comment: @Hodrobond Yes, it is the file's name.

Comment: `getSignedUrl` seems to be stinky then, if you're inputs are what's expected.

Comment: @Hodrobond I have solved this problem by avoiding using this bucket. I am very appreciate your help tho!